# Vagrant ifconfig command run but fails

Tags: vagrant

Want to run mutiple interfaces on same NIC.

Running Shell ifconfig command through  Vagrant file, command runs but it failed miserably .
Any workaround. T

```
 config.vm.define :custom_vm1 do |custom_vm1 |
    custom_vm1.vm.network :public_network,
         :dev => "br1",
         :type => "bridge",
         :ip => "10.132.251.127",
         :auto_config => "false",
         :netmask => "255.255.255.0"
    custom_vm1.vm.provision "shell",
         run: "always",
         inline: "sudo ifconfig \"eth1:1\" 10.132.251.128 netmask 255.255.255.0 up",
         privileged: "true"
     custom_vm1.vm.provision "shell",
         run: "always",
         inline: "sudo ifconfig \"eth1:2\" 10.132.251.129  netmask 255.255.255.0 up",
         privileged: "true"

   end
```

Error for command is :-
  I understand error means this vagrant shell doesn't have permission to run ifconfig command. But any ideas how we can get around this one

```
    DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: chmod +x '/tmp/vagrant-shell' && /tmp/vagrant-shell (sudo="true")
DEBUG ssh: stderr: 41e57d38-b4f7-4e46-9c38-13873d338b86-vagrant-ssh
DEBUG ssh: stderr: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address

 INFO interface: detail: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
 INFO interface: detail:     custom_vm1: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
    custom_vm1: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 255
```